# How to sort ENUM column in MySQL database?

Tags: sql, mysql, sorting, enums

I have `color` column in MySQL table which type is `ENUM('RED', 'YELLOW', 'MY_COLOR', 'BLACK')`, and another `name` column which type is `VARCHAR(30)`.

I would like to get all table rows in the following order:

- `YELLOW` rows first, sorted by `name`
- `RED` rows last, sorted by `name`
- In the middle, all other rows, sorted by `name`

Is that possible to make this kind of sort in 1 query ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY CASE color
           WHEN 'YELLOW' THEN 1
           WHEN 'RED' THEN 3
           ELSE 2
         END, name
```

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with mysql.  But for h2 DB it throws an error

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Order by expression "CASEWHEN((color = 'YELLOW'), 1, CASEWHEN((color = 'RED'),3))" must be in the result list in this case; SQL statement:

To avoid the error add the stmt `CASEWHEN((color = 'YELLOW'), 1, CASEWHEN((color = 'RED'),3))` in the select clause.