# ORDER BY column content MSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

For my content output i have three options in the table column 'Positie' (position) Here are the options: Keeper, Verdediging(Defender), Middenvelder(midfielder), and Aanvaller(attacker).

With my output i want it to be ordered by that the keepers come first than the defenders(Verdediging) than the Midfielders(Middenvelder) and than the attackers(Aanvaller).

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Team, Rugnummer, Positie FROM e2teams ORDER BY Positie DESC";
```

And it needs to be something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Team, Rugnummer, Positie FROM e2teams ORDER BY Positie, Keeper, Verdediging, Middenvelder, Aanvaller DESC";
```

I think,
Hope you can help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort ENUM column in MySQL database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965049/how-to-sort-enum-column-in-mysql-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `field()` for this:

```
SELECT ID, Team, Rugnummer, Positie
FROM e2teams
ORDER BY FIELD(Positie, 'Positie', 'Keeper', 'Verdediging', 'Middenvelder', 'Aanvaller')
```

Comment: Thnx this is the solution! thankyou i will mark it as the right answer in ten minutes